# How can I force a Ubuntu kernel to fail mounting / and drop into the initramfs rescue shell?

Tags: ubuntu, initrd, initramfs, rescue

I am trying to customize the initramfs rescue environment and would like to *force* the kernel to fail mounting `/` and drop into the `(initramfs)` rescue shell, as opposed to single user mode.

How can I do that?

NB: I know how to hook into `initramfs-tools` to achieve the customization steps, but I need to be able to verify the result.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This will drop you into an initramfs shell:

- Start your computer. Wait until the Grub menu appears.
- Hit <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot commands.
- Append `break=mount` to your kernel line.
- Hit <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
- Within a moment, you will find yourself in a initramfs shell.

If you want to make this behavior persistent, add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="break=mount"` to `/etc/default/grub` and run `grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg`.